# Evaluate $\int_0^2 x^2 e^{-x^3} \, dx$ using substitution

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

The integral in question is:

$$\int_0^2 x^2 e^{-x^3} \, dx.$$

I'm not sure if I should put $u=x^2$ and $du=2x\,dx$ which would lead to $(1/2)\,du=x\,dx$ or put $u=e^{-x^3}$ which I'm not sure would change anything since the derivative of $e^x$ is $e^x$.

Comment: Let $u=x^{3}$ then $du=3x^{2}dx$ and your integral would be $c \int e^{-u}du$ where $c$ is some non-zero constant you must determine from the substitution.

Comment: Interesting, thanks.

Comment: . . . and if $u=e^{-x^3}$ then $du = e^{-x^3} 3x^2\,dx$ and then you're almost done. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: After this, try solving $\int x^3e^{x^2}\,\mathrm dx$

Answer (score 5):

Better method:

$$\begin{align} \int^2_0 x^2e^{-x^3}dx &= - \frac{1}{3} \int^2_0 \frac{d}{dx}e^{-x^3}dx
\\
&= - \frac{1}{3} e^{-x^3}\bigg|_0^2 \\
\end{align}$$

Noticing this is somewhat similar to choosing the substitution $u=x^3$ (and therefore using $du=3x^2 dx$)

Answer (score 5):

I guess someone will answer using the substitution $\;u=x^3\;$ , but you don't really need this. Observe that using the Chain Rule, we have

$$\int f'(x)\,e^{f(x)}\;dx=e^{f(x)}+C$$

and in our case

$$x^2=-\frac13(-3x^2)=-\frac13(-x^3)'$$

so that

$$\int x^2e^{-x^3}dx=-\frac13\int(-x^3)'e^{-x^3}dx=-\frac13e^{-x^3}+C$$

Comment: A prefectly reasonable approach. I gave a comment under the OPs line, with the substitution you mention. I also noted that the Chain rule was set up for this but the OP asked for a hint regarding the method of substitution. Your proposed answer is more elegant; I often find it difficult to know whether what the OP asks for is indeed what they are asking for, or whether the answer lies in the best approach. Anyway, +1.

Comment: @Autolatry Thank you, and agree with you. The method I apply in this answer is something I've shown to many, many high school students and most of them utterly love them as *by the official syllabus* they're only taught substitution. That is very limiting imo.

Comment: "you don't really need this": what you are doing is exactly a substitution.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Not really: I'm more like **identifying**  some factor of the integrand function as the derivative of *another* factor. Among other advantages **and differences**, when doing what I did with Riemann integrals I don't need to change the limits of the integral. If at all, I'd say that whoever does the "logical" substitution here is doing *what  I did* . :)

Answer (score 1):

**By Inspection**: the term in front of the exponential ($x^2$) is the differential of the exponent ($x^3$). So what we can say is '*assume the solution to the integral is $I = e^{-x^3}$*'. Does this work? Lets check by differentiating this, which should give back the integrand that you have:

$\frac{d}{dx}e^{-x^3} = -3x^2\cdot e^{-x^3}$, by the chain rule and so we can see that our original solution was just off by a factor of -3. Hence our true solution is $\,-\frac{1}{3}e^{-x^3}$. This would be the ideal way of solving this since you can just see the answer.

**By substitution:** method requires that you take $u = x^3 \implies du = 3u^{\frac{2}{3}}dx$. Hence you get (omitting the limits):

$\int dx\,x^2e^{-x^3} \equiv \frac{1}{3}\int du \, e^{-u}$, which is easy to solve.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I consider a good hint:
$$
\int_0^2 e^{-x^3}\Big(x^2 \, dx\Big)
$$

If anyone doesn't understand this hint, then that immediately tells me specifically what they need to work on understanding.